# wherehas different result from count over the db

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, has-many

I've a m:n relations beetween `Regions` and `Trees`, with a pivot table tree_region;

Region's model:

```php
class Region extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'regions';
    public function trees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Trees', 'tree_region', 'idTree', 'region' );    
    }    
}
```

Tree's Model:

```php
class Tree extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'trees';
    public function regions()    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Region', 'tree_region', 'region', 'idTree' );
    }
}
```

In TreesController i've a function that i use for find trees by region:

```php
public function treesByRegion(Request $request){
    $region = $request->region;
    $trees = Tree::whereHas('regions', function (Builder $query) use($region){
            $query->where('name', 'like','%'.$region.'%' );
        })->with('regions')->get();  
    return response()->json(count($trees));
}
```

For example if I pass a string present on the db, the result is different from :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `tree_region` WHERE `region`=1
```

Executed over the db, pivot table with the same id as the string 'regions' rappresent.
What I wrong?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, what's the result you expect? and what are you getting?

Comment: the count over the collection give me 18, the count over the db give me 55!

Comment: If the region is just an integer, then why are you doing a `LIKE` query?

Comment: Are you models using `SoftDeletes`? Laravel will ignore deleted records by default, a manual query will not (unless you specified `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`)

Comment: no there is no softdeleting fields on the db

Comment: @CaddyDZ because its a string and i suppose to extract ids from pivots with such kind of function

Comment: what is the result if you just use the Eloquent relationship from your model?  i.e. `dd($request->region->trees()->count());`

Comment: @Erich g it raise an error to call trees() over a string; I've tried even this variant:` $region=$request->region;
        $regionz=Region::where('name',$region)->first()->id;
        $trees=Tree::whereHas('regions', function (Builder $query) use($regionz){
            $query->where('name', '=',$regionz);
        })->get();  ` And it give me the same result as the code posted before

Comment: sorry, try this: `$region = Region::find($request->region); dd($region->trees()->count());`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a "normal" many to many relationship.  Each `Region` can have many different `Tree`s, and each `Tree` can exist in many different `Region`s.

Your Eloquent relationships are already set up, so I would leverage them for all your needs.  You can even encapsulate this in a method belonging to each parent model:

```php
// Region.php

public function countTrees()
{
    return $this->trees()->count();
}
```

and

```php
// Tree.php

public function countRegions()
{
    return $this->regions()->count();
}
```

Note: by calling `count()` on `regions()` (as opposed to `regions` without the `()`), the computation will be performed in SQL via a single query.  Good for one-off lookups, but not at scale due to n+1 problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply the problem for me is not to write a function inside the model, but understand why if I run a query over  the db on the same data, and the result is so far from what i get from eloquent/laravel code above...

Comment: does your pivot table have orphaned entries in it?  is this an existing database or brand new to your project?  if brand new, i highly recommend letting Laravel manage the relationships, and take out the extra params in your `belongsToMany()` relationships.

Comment: Im using a variant with the id  as commentend above same result as like version...18 over 55 on the db... i got same result with like and string(the req contains the string value of the id 1->Abruzzo for example) what I wrong?

Comment: what do you get when you `dd(Region::find(1)->trees()->count());`?

Comment: no the table is clean... the only thing is that i dint build from Laravel with migrations. the pivot table got 'id','idTree','region' all referenced on each table (from phpmyadmin you can walk over every records to is "original" so I assume thats relations works!)

Comment: ` dd(Region::find(1)->trees()->count());`  give me 19